# Only selected view/area can drag the BottomSheet

Tags: android, android-support-library, bottom-sheet

Im having a problem in dragging bottomsheet with nestedscrollview.

Is there a way to set the view as the draggable part of BottomSheet ?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73903301/3575423

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BottomSheetBehavior - only allow dragging on part of view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71474605/bottomsheetbehavior-only-allow-dragging-on-part-of-view)