# BottomSheetBehavior - only allow dragging on part of view

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, android-nestedscrollview

I have a bottom sheet implemented using BottomSheetBehavior within a CoordinatorLayout. My BottomSheet has a top appbar sort of title bar, and then some scrollable content. Something like this.

[image]

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    ...

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        ...

    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want the user to be able to drag the bottom sheet to the expanded, half-expanded, and hidden positions, but ***only*** when dragging the bottom sheet's top appbar. So if the bottom sheet is at the half-expanded state, dragging/scrolling/flinging the scrollable content within the bottom sheet should ***not*** adjust it's position - it should remain half-expanded. But dragging the top appbar up/down should cause the bottom sheet to perform its normal draggable behavior.

Is this possible with BottomSheetBehavior?

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but answering so it may help someone.

Try following:

- Extend `BottomSheetBehaviour` to create your own `CustomDraggableBottomSheetBehaviour`
- In your `CustomDraggableBottomSheetBehaviour` override `onInterceptTouchEvent()` and use `isDraggable` property to enable/disable dragging if touch points are inside your "specific" view.
- In your xml layout file provide reference to your `CustomDraggableBottomSheetBehaviour`
  `app:layout_behaviour="com.myapp.CustomDraggableBottomSheetBehaviour"`

Here is an example of that class in kotlin:

```
class CustomDraggableBottomSheetBehaviour<V: View>: BottomSheetBehaviour<V> {
   var draggableView: View? = null

   constructor(): super()
   constructor(ctx: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): super(ctx, attrs)

   override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(parent: CoordinatorLayout, child: V, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
      draggableView?.let {
         isDraggable = parent.isPointInChildBounds(it, event.x.toInt(), event.y.toInt())
      }
      return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(parent, child, event)
   }
}
```

Just assign the `draggableView` property to your 'Top AppBar' on object received by `BottomSheetBehaviour.from(someViewGoup)`

Comment: How can I apply `CustomDraggableBottomSheetBehaviour` to Modal BottomSheet?

Comment: @MinseongPark you solve this problem with ModalBottomSheet?  i have the same issue.

Comment: Can you provide more information about how to not do it through XML instead by code?